# Java OOP not able to add specific element from arraylist to another arraylist

Tags: java, oop

I have an arraylist named teamList, where I have a list of custom object named Team.

I want to find a specific object in this arrayList. When I find this object, I want to use my constructor 'addPlayer' to Team, that has its own arrayList named 'playersList'.

I am able to find the team that I want to specifically find, however I am not able to use the 'addPlayer' constructor.

I am attempting to here:

```
@FXML public void AddingPlayer() {
        Player player = new Player(newPlayerTextfield.getText());
        Object currVal = newPlayerDropdown.getValue();
        for (Object t : teams.getTeamList()){
            if (t.equals(currVal)){
                 System.out.println(teams.getTeamList().indexOf(t));
                 //t.addPlayer(player);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also I wanted to use a for(i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++), but for some reason size() was highlighted in red, and with no error message.

Sorry for obvious mistakes, I am new to programming

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this :

```
for (Object t : teams.getTeamList()){
```

Try to do so:

```
for (Team t : teams.getTeamList()){
```